# Is it a Transitive Relationship

Tags: functions, relations, equivalence-relations

Let Z be the set of integers. Then, is the relation
$R = \{ (a,b):1+ab>0\}$ on Z transitive?

Comment: What do you think? What does it _mean_ for a relation to be transitive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. counterexample: $a=1, b=0, c =-1$